# Mysql regexp to allow numbers and '+'

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a mysql table with a column that has phone numbers in it - some aren't really phone numbers, which I want to find out by firing a single query that says something like "set all phone numbers to NULL where the phone number consists of other characters than 0-9 and '+'"

So far I have come up with the following, but do not know how to add tolerance for '+':

```
$query="UPDATE table SET phone='NULL' WHERE phone REGEXP ('[0-9]')!=1";
mysql_query($query);
```

Does anybody know how to tolerate '+' in that query? Also, the '+' needs to be at the beginning of the phone number.

Thank you!

Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `NOT REGEXP` instead of `!=1`.  To allow `+` at the start optionally, use `^\\+?`.  Since `+` is a special character in regular expressions, it must be escaped with a backslash (which must be escaped with another backslash).  You then need one or more digits (`[0-9]+`), up to the end of the string `$`.

```
$query="UPDATE table SET phone='NULL' WHERE phone NOT REGEXP '^\+?[0-9]+$'";
```

This will match anything that doesn't begin optionally with `+`, followed by digits only.  If you also need to permit hyphens and dots in the phone number, add them into the `[]` character class:

```
'^\\+?[0-9.-]+$'
```

Comment: Thanks! The '+' is not optional, so do I just have to get rid of the '?' ?

Comment: Looks good so far, but when I test the following query:
"SELECT * FROM `hosts` WHERE phone NOT REGEXP ('^\+?[0-9]+$')" I get the error "#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp" - How come?

Comment: @Charles Looks like you need a double backslash `\\+`  The first escapes the second to be used as a literal in the regex. Otherwise MySQL eats it as an escape character.